# display the data json responses using javascript or in console

Tags: javascript, json

I have a page that has much data I want to use. I inspected the page with Google Chrome to find the URL of the data (Network XHR). I get the request URL and when I open it, it does not show me anything, but in the preview and in the responses I can see the data. I tested some JavaScript codes to get JSON data from this URL, but it always errors.

I tested some command in console to display the text responses in console but nothing please I need your help to get this data using JavaScript

some codes I tested:

```
fetch( 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?&action=get_vehicles' )
     .then( response => response.text() )
     .then( response => {
     .then(function(data) {
     console.log(data.data);
       } );
```

`

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKbim.png)
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZj49.png)

[responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUsvK.png)
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmsNr.png)

Comment: What does "when i open it ,it dosenot show me anything, but in the previw and in the responses i can see the data" mean? Does it have a response, or does it not have a response? Also, "i tested some codes javascript to get data json": what code? Show that in your post. And a second time, "i tested some command in console to display the text responses in console", what code? Show it in your post. Remember, this is _not_ a general help forum, [follow the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Did you copy&paste that snippet? Not sure it’s syntactically correct, could be part of the reason for the errors you are encountering.

Comment: Maybe you need headers set.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the fetch api call by going in the network tab in Chrome Developer Tools, clicking with right button in the request and then clicking in copy > copy as fetch like so:

[image]

Comment: It copys a Javascript fetch call

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?&action=get_vehicles")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: thank you Sir  Eliabe França, i tested the method by copying as clicking with right button in the request and then clicking in copy > copy as fetch as you told , but i want to use the javascript to extract the text responses i see to store it in google database firebase

Comment: i can see my text (data json) by cliking copy> copy responses but how can i get it by javascript

Comment: my question why when i put the url request  , the page dosn"t show me the data json , it dipslayed only when i go to inspect > network > XHR > preview or responses

Comment: Yes Mr gambino  ,i tested many code more than 50 codes , many function ... fetch , XMLHttpRequest() , parsing(), ...

Comment: here my headers   ;  href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKbim.png"